# "Collateral" VS "Stationery"

Tags: print-design, terminology

What does "Collateral" means in the printing world and how does that differ from "Stationery"?

People usually use the word collateral when mentioning stationery. I would like to know what is the difference between them and what each word represents.

Answer (score 5):

Station**E**ry is usually just printed Letterheads, Business cards, Envelopes and such office supplies.
Collateral (at least how we use the term) is all secondary material which may be included in a package which you send out. This could be Flyers and Brochures, Datasheets, CDs, (even Giveaways) and things like that.